# Trouble importing third party Python packages to GIMP 2.10 so that they can be used to write GIMP plugins

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, gimp, gimpfu

My goal is to import a couple third party Python packages for use with my GIMP installation. This will allow me to use these packages when developing a GIMP plugin. I noticed a few directories that may be of use. They are as follows:

C:\Program Files\GIMP 2\32\lib\python2.7

This directory contains a site-packages folder which contains packages such as requests and pip.

C:\Program Files\GIMP 2\32\bin

This directory contains a python.exe. When I run python --version in an elevated cmd at this directory path, the output is Python 2.7.16, which I assume is GIMP 2.10's version of Python. This is important because I have my own installation of Python 3.8.0 in my Program Files. If I'm anywhere outside of this path in the cmd, the version that outputs is 3.8.0.

I have added these directories to my PATH system variable and tried running pip install but the output tells me I have already installed the requested third party packages. The problem is that they are installed to my Python 3.8.0 installation. I'm trying to run pip install in the context of GIMP's Python environment.

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: Does the directory `C:\Program Files\GIMP 2\32\bin` have a `pip` executable or a file named `pip`?

Comment: No it does not.

Comment: It is guess that the embedded version of the Python included with GIMP does not have pip package manager installed. You would probably need to install the third party libraries manually using the `setup.py` or `easy_install`.

Comment: I found easy_install.py, easy_install.pyc, and easy_install.pyo in C:\Program Files\GIMP 2\32\lib\python2.7\site-packages. Can you guide me towards what I should be doing next? Should I run easy_install ... in the cmd while in C:\Program Files\GIMP 2\32\lib\python2.7\site-packages?

Comment: When I run easy_install in cmd it just opens that script.

Answer (score 1):

- Grab `get-pip.py` [here](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py)
- Put it into your GIMP Python directory (C:\Program Files\GIMP 2\Python)
- From a Windows Command Prompt Window `cd` to that directory
- Run `get-pip` **with this python instance**: `.\python.exe get-pip.py`. You now have pip installed in the GIMP version of Python.
- You can now use this pip instance with Gimp's Python runtime: `.\python.exe -m pip install --user <package>`

Uplifted/adapted from [here](https://www.gimp-forum.net/Thread-Gimp-python-and-numpy?pid=4385#pid4385)

Comment: Thanks for the response. Firstly, I don't have a Python folder that proceeds my GIMP folder. I was able to find the python.exe which was:

C:\Program Files\GIMP 2\32\bin

From here I was able to run 

.\python.exe get-pip.py

...but I got errors.

After this, I tried .\python.exe -m easy_install --user <thirdparty.tar>

This command downloaded the .tar but output the following error:

error: Setup script exited with error: command 'i686-w64-mingw32-gcc' failed: No such file or directory

Comment: Is this Gimp 2.8? Looks like the package requires to compile something, which is odd. What specific package is this?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the package I was trying install had dependencies that required a higher version of Python than the one GIMP comes with. Thanks to those whom responded.